# Airflow Docker - NameError when importing function into DAG

Tags: python, docker, airflow, nameerror

I'm currently attempting to build a data pipeline using the puckel docker-airflow 1.10.9 image on windows.

When the functions are called to the DAG from within the DAG file, it works well and I can access the output of the code.

However, when I try to import the function from the my_scripts directory at the same level as my_dags directory, I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'reorder_columns' is not defined
```

Below is the folder structure that I am using for my airflow:

```
airflow
|
dags
├── dockerfiles
|    ├── Dockerfile 
|
├── docker-compose.yml
|
├── trading_pipeline
│   ├── my_dags
│   │   ├── demand_forecast_dag.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── DataStore.py
|   ├── my_scripts
│   |    ├── demand_forecast.py
│   |    ├── __init__.py
|   |
|   ├── __init__.py
|
├── __init__.py
```

Below is the demand_forecast_dag file:

```
try:

    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
    import requests
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import pandas as pd
    import DataStore
    import os
    import datetime

    from dags.trading_pipeline.my_scripts.demand_forecast import reorder_columns

    print("All DAG modules are ok......")

except Exception as e:

    print("Error {} ".format(e))

col_name_1 = "Demand_Forecast"
col_name_2 = "Settlement_Period"
col_name_3 = "Date"

with DAG(
    dag_id="demand_forecast_dag",
    schedule_interval='0 9 * * *',
    default_args={
                       "owner": "airflow",
                       "retries": 1,
                       "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
                       "start_date": datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
                   },
        catchup=False) as f:

    get_demand_forecast = PythonOperator(
        task_id="reorder_columns",
        python_callable=reorder_columns,
        op_args=[col_name_1, col_name_2, col_name_3]
    )
```

Below is the demand_forecast.py file that the function is being imported into the DAG from:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import DataStore
import os
import datetime

settlement_datetime = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
required_date = settlement_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

col_name_1 = "Demand_Forecast"
col_name_2 = "Settlement_Period"
col_name_3 = "Date"


def clock_change_sp(settlement_date):
    """when there is a clock change, there is a different number of settlement periods, this function uses the
    DataStore file to determine the number of sp based on if the required date is a clock change
    :param settlement_date: uses the settlement date at the top of the script
    :return x + 1: the number of required settlement periods plus 1"""
    if settlement_date in DataStore.clocks_forward:
        x = 46
    elif settlement_date in DataStore.clocks_back:
        x = 50
    else:
        x = 48
    return x + 1


def get_demand_forecast(date):
    api_key = "....."
    """uses the BMReports API to pull in the demand forecast for each settlement period of the following day
    :param self: uses the settlement_date and api_key from the Data class
    :return: a list of the demand forecast for the following day"""
    initial_data_list = []
    session = requests.Session()
    for x in range(0, 1, 1):
        url = "https://api.bmreports.com/BMRS/FORDAYDEM/V1?APIKey=" + api_key + "&FromDate=" + date + "&ToDate=" + date + "&ServiceType=xml"
        response = session.get(url)
        request_data = response.text
        root = ET.fromstring(request_data)
        for item in root.findall('.//responseBody/responseList/item/demand'):
            initial_data_list.append(item.text)
    demand_forecast_list = initial_data_list[:clock_change_sp(required_date)-1:]
    return demand_forecast_list


def create_dataframes(col_1):
    """converts the list required list from above into a dataframe, converts it to GW and rounds to 2dp
    :param self: inherits the demand_forecast_list from the previous function, plus col_name_1, which is the name
    of the data column "Demand Forecast"
    :return df: a dataframe with the required data in GW and rounded to 2dp
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(get_demand_forecast(required_date), columns=[col_1])
    df[col_1] = df[col_1].astype(str).astype(int)
    df[col_1] = df[col_1].div(1000).round(2)
    # print(df)
    return df


def add_dates_and_sp(col_2, col_3, settlement_date):
    """adds the selected date and settlement periods to the dataframe
    :param self: inherits the dataframe from the previous function, the number of settlement periods from the first function,
    plus col_name_2 and col_name_3 which are the SP and Date column names respectively
    :return df: a dataframe with all the collected data plus the Date and Settlement Period"""
    df = create_dataframes(col_name_1)
    df[col_2] = list(range(1, clock_change_sp(required_date)))
    df[col_3] = settlement_date
    # print(df)
    return df


def reorder_columns(col_1, col_2, col_3):
    """reorders the columns so that it reads more easily
    :param self: the dataframe from the previous function with all the data but in the wrong order
    :return df: a dataframe with the columns in the required order"""
    df = add_dates_and_sp(col_2, col_3, required_date)[[col_3, col_2, col_1]]
    print(df)
    return df
```

I am fairly new to airflow and docker so apologies if this is a simple error.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance,

Josh

Answer (score 1):

After some troubleshooting and reading more Stack Overflow articles I managed to import the function from the script in another folder.

There were two parts to it, the first involved setting my AIRFLOW_HOME and PYTHONPATH in my Dockerfile:

```
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:C:/Users/name/airflow/dags"
```

I also added some volumes into my docker-compose.yml file:

```
volumes:
- ./trading_pipeline/my_dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
- ./trading_pipeline/my_scripts:/usr/local/airflow/dags/trading_pipeline
```

Not sure if this is the best method but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to always have a separate file for functions to have a clean code but you don't have to import a single function you can easily import like this by file name I think your import is wrong you can import like this **

> from demand_forecast import *

**  Also import os and sys and file import so that it can read the file as of know it is not reading the files **

> import os
>
> import sys
>
> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**)))**

you can use python collab but you can also like do this method like

var1 =  reorder_columns(col_1, col_2, col_3)

and then put the var 1 in your python collab

try this and let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kaolin. 

Unfortunately your solution did not work, however, I did manage to resolve it as per my answer below.